# Use \textquotedbl in repeating cells in pgfplotstable

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfplotstable

I have Table 1. Repeating values in consecutive cells of a column should be replaced with `\textquotedbl` as in Table 2. Also `\textquotedbl` should be aligned centered according to column width although numbers are aligned right.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{filecontents}{testdataExisting.dat}
id val
1  5634
2  78945
3  78945
4  689623
5  14514
6  14514
7  14514
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testdataGenerated.dat}
id val
1  5634
2  78945
3  \textquotedbl
4  689623
5  14514
6  \textquotedbl
7  \textquotedbl
\end{filecontents}

 \begin{document}
Table 1

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,val},
     columns/val/.style={fixed,precision=0,column type=r},
 ]{testdataExisting.dat}

Table 2

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,val},
   %  columns/val/.style={fixed,precision=0,column type=r},
    columns/val/.style={string type,column type=r},
 ]{testdataGenerated.dat}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

In the solution, `testdataGenerated.dat` should not exist. I need a solution that postprocesses the table of `testdataExisting.dat` so that it replaces repeating values with `\textquotedbl` and align these `\textquotedbl`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new column on the fly with the duplicate values replaced by quotes as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.6}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{filecontents}{testdataExisting.dat}
id val
1  5634
2  78945
3  78945
4  689623
5  14514
6  14514
7  14514
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{testdataExisting.dat}\origtable

 \begin{document}
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
   Table 1
   \medskip

   \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,val},
   columns/val/.style={fixed,precision=0,column type=r}, ]\origtable
 \end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
  Table 2
  \medskip

  \pgfplotstableset{create on use/newval/.style={create
  col/assign/.code={
  \getthisrow{val}\curval\getprevrow{val}\pval\ifx\curval\pval\def\curval{\textquotedbl}\fi
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\curval}}}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,newval},
  columns/newval/.style={string type,column type=r,column name={Value}}, ]\origtable
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The original data is stored in `\origtable`.  We print this essentially as it stands in the first instance.  In the second, we provide `create on use` code that takes the current value in `\curval` and the previous value in `\pval`, compares them and passes the required output to `next content`.

One way to specify the formatting of the numbers in the new string column is to format these numbers when defining the entries in an `\else` clause of the comparison with the previous line:

```
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/newval/.style={create
  col/assign/.code={
  \getthisrow{val}\curval\getprevrow{val}\pval
  \ifx\curval\pval\def\curval{\textquotedbl}\else
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto{\curval}\curval\fi
  \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\curval}}}
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,columns={id,newval},
  columns/newval/.style={string type,column type=r,column name={Value}}, ]\origtable
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Dear @AndrewSwann, is it possible to preserve the format of the numbers in the new table? The thousands separator in numbers has great importance since other columns in my original table must have thousands separators also.

Comment: I have now added code for this.